# Podemos combinar as tags C# com VB?

Tags: debate, status-recusado, tags

Ambas são linguagens distintas, porém do mesmo mundo, o famoso .NET Framework, mas, há muitas ferramentas de conversões online de C# para Visual Basic e vice-versa. Eu tinha mania de postar uma pergunta e colocar ambas as *tags*, quando alguém postava na linguagem oposta que eu estava desenvolvendo não tinha problema, pois era muito fácil "traduzir" ela.

Por que fazia isso? O recurso de "tags favoritas" deixa em amarelo as perguntas "feitas para você", por exemplo, tenho ambas tags como favoritas, e perguntas delas são enfatizadas, atraindo mais atenção para alguém responder.

Há algum problema em fazer isso?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Imagino que esteja falando de [c#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) e [vb.net](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net), a [vb](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb) é para o Visual Basic antigo que não funciona com o .Net.

Quando coloca ambas está indicando que aceita uma solução para qualquer uma delas. O que até funciona, mas não é o que deseja. .O ideal é colocar apenas a *tag* que deseja. Então aconselho não misturar mais.